# Unable to bind observale collection to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an Observable Collection, which I am trying to bind to an ItemsControl. The following is the snippet from my code.

**Class Sample.ViewModel:**

```
//Observabale collection getter/setter property
public ObservableCollection<SQuestion> SList
{
    get
    {             
        return _sList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_sList == value)
            return;
        _sList = value;
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListOfSamples"));
    }
}
```

**.xaml code:**
**View/Mainwindow.xaml**

```
<ItemsControl Height="422" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="751" ItemsSource="{Binding SList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource perItemTemplate}"/>
```

In the above code, I have the specified the ItemsSource Binding but on running my application, the list does not appear in the ItemsControl and everything appears blank.:
However, if I try to assign the source to Listbox from my .cs code-behind as `listBox1.ItemsSource = SList`, the list box gets populated and works as expected.
Can somebody point what's the problem in the above with Binding that I am doing so that I can bind from xaml directly and not using code-behind?

Comment: How/where do you set the `DataContext` for your Mainwindow? Are there any binding errors in the VisualStudio's Output window during runtime? By the way when you raise `PropertyChanged` you should use the name of your property e.g.: you should write `new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SList")`

Comment: @nemesv: I added this line while loading the application - `this.DataContent = _collection.SList;` and this makes the application run fine. However, I didn't know about `DataContext` and the other thing you pointed about. Can you pass a link where I could learn this up quickly. (Beginner in WPF related stuff)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

In CodeBehind:

```
public void MyInitialization()
{
    listBox1.DataContext = SList;
}

//Observabale collection getter/setter property
public ObservableCollection<SQuestion> SList 
{ 
    get 
    {              
        return _sList; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        if (_sList == value) 
            return; 
        _sList = value; 
        if(PropertyChanged!= null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SList")); 
    } 
}
```

In Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Height="422" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="751" ItemsSource="{Binding} 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource perItemTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your property name in VM is `SList` but you are rising PropertyChange with different name: `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListOfSamples"));`. Replace it with `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SList"));` and should be good (assuming VM is wired correctly)